# create a login page which allow user to register with his facebook account

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have to create an app in android which will allow users to login in with their facebook account....if his mobile is connected to the internet.

Could someone give me a hint/example of how could that be done?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try following this tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) it will take you through step by step on how to set up for application to use facebook. It also goes through how to setup the keys etc. Hope this helps!